# ¿Existe alguna palabra que cubra el significado de "underdog" en inglés?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

En inglés, "underdog" es el contendiente que no es favorito en una confrontación.

Estoy rompiéndome la cabeza buscando una palabra en castellano que se pueda aplicar a esa definición, pero no encuentro nada. Sé que podría decir simplemente "el no favorito", pero me pregunto si hay algo más elegante.

Comment: Esta estaba en mi lista de cosas para preguntar. De [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdog_(competici%C3%B3n)): *No existe una palabra específica en español que sea equivalente a underdog, salvo que se use frases como: perdedor esperado, el que se espera que pierda, el que no es favorito, el que lleva las de perder, el que va de punto, etc.*

Comment: ¿Se usa siempre en confrontaciones uno a uno? Es decir, ¿sería el "perdedor esperado" o puede ser simplemente el no-ganador de entre otras personas?

Comment: @Diego de hecho mi primera suposición cuando leí el título de la pregunta es que la habías hecho tú. :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el mundo del fútbol y otros deportes, es muy común utilizar ***cenicienta*** en este sentido: se trata del equipo de una competición que en principio es el más vulnerable y fácilmente derrotable. No lo he oído en casos de confrontación uno a uno, como sería el caso de deportes individuales.

Algunos casos:

- Marca: [*La 'cenicienta' llega al Reyno*](https://www.marca.com/2010/10/02/futbol/1adivision/1286051453.html)
- Marca: [*La 'cenicienta' de la Copa, el Benidorm, se mete en la final*](https://www.marca.com/balonmano/2020/03/07/5e63e529e2704ec54f8b460b.html)
- El País: [*Bolivia, la cenicienta de las alturas*](https://elpais.com/deportes/2015/06/09/actualidad/1433859672_906420.html)

Probablemente se use como copia del término inglés descrito en la Wikipedia en su artículo [*Cinderella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_(sports)), que de hecho está referenciado en [el artículo sobre *underdog*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdog).

Comment: Buena opción. La voz _[cenicienta](https://dle.rae.es/cenicienta)_ la puedes encontrar de hecho en el DLE con el significado de "persona o cosa injustamente postergada, despreciada".

Comment: "cenicienta" también se usa en inglés con la.midma intención: "that Cinderella team won 8 matches in a row"

Answer (score 5):

The essential characteristic of an underdog is that they are expected to lose, nothing more. As an English gentleman I was brought up to believe that I should always support the underdog. I remember a cartoon from the distant past when we had a particularly close parliamentary election. The aristocratic lady of the house was leaving to get into her Rolls-Royce to go to vote and asked her servant "Which party is the underdog?" the joke being of course that nobody actually knew. Having said that:

The phrase in Wikipedia *perdedor esperado* seems literally what is meant by underdog but is not very snappy.

A neat suggestion by @Charlie *segundón* seems much closer to what we mean.

Of other suggestions *víctima* is too strong as my example above suggests. I think *cenicienta* possibly has too many other layers of meaning to fit all cases where we use underdog but it might sometimes work.

Answer (score 3):

He encontrado una opción que me parece muy interesante tras buscar en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España y toparme con esto:

> *El Leicester City aparece a todas luces como víctima, el «underdog», como dicen en las Islas...*
>
> Marca (Madrid). 5/5/1961, página 14.

Según el diccionario:

> **[víctima](https://dle.rae.es/v%C3%ADctima)**
>
> Del lat. *victĭma*.
>
> 1. f. Persona o animal sacrificado o destinado al sacrificio.
> 2. f. Persona que se expone u ofrece a un grave riesgo en obsequio de otra.

Hay más definiciones, pero cualquiera de estas dos podría servir para denominar al contendiente que va a ser "sacrificado" en favor del otro, el favorito. Por tanto, en una lucha entre dos contendientes me parecería sensato hablar del "favorito" y de la "víctima".

Veo este uso de *víctima* en otros ejemplares de la hemeroteca, junto con otras expresiones compuestas por más de una palabra:

- El que parte en desventaja.
- La opción contra pronóstico.

Y otra opción, que puede estar bien como contraposición a *favorito* y que también he visto en algún ejemplar de la hemeroteca: el [desvalido](https://dle.rae.es/desvalido). Y otra más, ya puestos: el [segundón](https://dle.rae.es/segund%C3%B3n).